# Php - Ajax : Display a specific row information from a while loop by clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a project where the user is connected and can see the list of his own delivery order.
The delivery list is diplayed using a while loop. 
When clicking on details button of an item in the list, I need to display the details of this item from the loop using his id (basically the content of the row id).
I all time got an an empty details... and don't understand because it works with hardocded ids in my ajax request

Here is my index.php files

```
    <?php
     include('config.php');
    // if connection to db ok,continue
   // We prepare the request that join the table users and delivrey based on the user id
    $reqdelivery = $bdd->prepare("SELECT users.id, livraisons.id, livraisons.user_id, livraisons.delivery_date, livraisons.recipient_address, livraisons.recipient_name
                        FROM livraisons
                        INNER JOIN users
                        ON users.id = user_id
                        WHERE users.id = ?
                        ORDER BY delivery_date");
    $reqdelivery->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));


    while ($donnees = $reqdelivery->fetch())
    {      

    ?>    
    // Add data to every field of the page
   <tr class="delivery_board_menu_data">
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_date"><?php echo $donnees['delivery_date']; ?></td>
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_recipient"><?php echo $donnees['recipient_name']; ?></td>
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_address"><?php echo $donnees['recipient_address']; ?></td>
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_type">Express</td>
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_price">1</td>

    // More button that display the box option using JQuery
    <td class="delivery_board_menu_data_more"><a href="#" class="data_more_informations">More</a></td>


    <!-- Div with box option content -->
    <td class="div_data_more_informations">
         <ul>
            //Detail button that display the details page
            <li><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>" class="div_data_more_informations_details">Détails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="div_data_more_informations_cancel">Annuler</a></li>
         </ul>
    </td>
    <!-- End Div avec contenu de la box option -->
 </tr>

 <?php
 }

 // We finish the request when all all table has been check
 $reqdelivery->closeCursor();
 ?>



<!-- Start Slide menu details/livraison -->
// Include the details.php sheet
<div id="container-details">
<?php include ('details.php') ;?>
</div>
<!-- End Slide menu details/livraison -->
```

My details.php files

```
<?php

 include('config.php'); 
// prepare the request that display the delivery details thanks to the delivery id

$result = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM livraisons WHERE id = ?");
$result->execute(array($_GET['id']));  

// While loop to check all the data
while ($donnees_details = $result->fetch())
{                                        
?> 

<!-- Start Slide menu details/livraison -->
<div class="container-details_header">
   <span id="close"></span>

   // display the data from the db row
   <p class="container-details_header_date">Livraison le <?php echo $donnees_details['delivery_date']; ?></p>
   <p class="container-details_header_type">Tournée</p>
</div>

<!-- Start détails de la livraison -->
   <div class="container-details_body">
   <!-- Start détails de la livraison INFOS -->
   <div class="container-details_body_infos">
       <p class="container-details_body_infos_title">Infos</p>
       <p class="container-details_body_infos_time"><span><?php echo $donnees_details['delivery_time']; ?></span> Heure de début</p>
       <p class="container-details_body_infos_volume"><span><?php echo $donnees_details['delivery_volume']; ?></span> Caisse de mesure</p>
      <div class="container-details_body_infos_separator"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End détails de la livraison INFOS -->
</div>
<!-- End Slide menu details/livraison -->


 <?php
  }
  // Close the cursor
 $reqdelivery->closeCursor();
 ?>
```

My Ajax script

```
   $.ajax({
     url: 'details.php',
     type : 'GET',
     data : 'id=' + id,
     dataType : 'html',

     success: function(data) {

         //#countainer-details open the delivery details panel using JQuery
         $('#container-details').html(data);

     }
});
```

Comment: Can you show more of the Ajax Script? How are you populating the `id` variable?

Comment: It's all my Ajax Script. I'm really new at ajax. The id is the one you get by clicking on: 
             <li><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $donnees['id']; ?>" class="div_data_more_informations_details">Détails</a></li>.
 Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could take is to watch for the `click` event on the link, parse the id, and then make your `ajax` call.

Something like the following:

Add a data-id attribute to your links:

```
<td class="div_data_more_informations">
     <ul>
        //Detail button that display the details page
        <li><a data-id="<?php echo $donnees['id'] ?>" href="#">Details</a></li>
     </ul>
</td>
```

Ajax Script:

```
<script>
  //Get all your links
  var links = $(".div_data_more_informations ul li a");

  //Loop through links and add on click listeners
  links.each(function(){
     var link = $(this);
     var id = link.data('id');

     link.click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'details.php',
            type : 'GET',
            data : 'id=' + id,
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function(data) {
               $('#container-details').html(data);
            }

       //prevent the link from refreshing page
       return false;
     });
  });

</script>
```

For more information about the `click` event: https://api.jquery.com/click/ 
and the `each` function: https://api.jquery.com/each/

You could also simplify the code using the `.get` method instead of the `$.ajax` call: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get('details.php', { "id" : id }, function(data){
    $('#container-details').html(data);
})
```